# Convert string to Control name c# wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

In my MainPage.xaml, there are 20 button controls named btn1, btn2, btn3, ... ... btn20. Now I need to use this buttons in code behind.

I'm planning on using a for loop and do the code for every button. But my problem is I'm not being able to convert string to Button name.

For example,

```
for (int i = 1; i <=20; i++)
{
     string button = "btn" + i;

     // Convert string to button somehow
     // Do something with button
}
```

I've searched on Google and there's plenty of articles about conversion of control name from string. But they are for Windows Forms. Windows phone apps do not support those namespaces.

Comment: What do you mean with converting string to control name? Do you mean instantiating a control class just knowing its name? For example, `TextBox`?

Comment: I've edited my question. Check it

Comment: Ah, I see. I understand the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
for (int i = 1; i <=20; i++)
{
       Button ele =  (Button) MainGrid.FindName("btn"+i);
}
```

Here MainGrid is the name of the Grid element which has button controls

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Almost 90% correct. But you missed a line.

Comment: @ShahriarSirajSnigdho As I said in your own auto-answer, you should point Archana how to improve his/her own answer, and BTW, there's nothing wrong on this answer. It just gave you the hint. Using `is` and later `as` is casting the object twice, right, but for me it's not enough to don't consider this answer as the right one.........

Comment: I have just written "is" condition. If your damn sure that its button element then you can remove that line

Comment: Your if condition doesn't matter. Because I'm try to find button from xaml page and of course I'm sure that the name I'm searching for is a button. But if you don't add this line `Button button = ele as Button;` your code will not work. Try it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Button ele =  (Button) MainGrid.FindName("button"); wiil work. Check the updated answer

Comment: Yes but it wasn't there in your previous answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't *convert a string to the button instance* but you need to get `btnN` (f.e. `btn1`) class field value using *reflection*:

```
Button button = (Button)GetType().GetField($"btn{i}", BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this);
```

Or even an more efficient way: use a dictionary to lookup buttons:

```
// Place this in your form constructor
Dictionary<string, Button> buttons = new Dictionary<string, Button>
{
    { "btn1", btn1 },
    { "btnN", btn2 }
};

// and later where you want to get your buttons by their name...
Button btn1 = buttons[$"btn{i}"];
```

Comment: GetField and BindingFlags do not exist in current context :(

Comment: @ShahriarSirajSnigdho Really? ;) Did you call `GetType().GetField()` or `GetField()` directly? And BindingFlags is a member of `System.Reflection` namespace... add an using to the whole namespace

Comment: @ShahriarSirajSnigdho BTW, why don't you go with the 2nd approach? The one using the dictionary. It's better than reflection in terms of efficiency

Comment: To be honest, I didn't think that any of these is an efficient approach

Comment: @ShahriarSirajSnigdho This conclusion is your own opinion. Dictionaries have constant access time regardless of their size. More efficient than this is impossible :D

Comment: @ShahriarSirajSnigdho Probably FindName has a dictionary under the hoods!

Comment: well, writing code like that (from answer) is easier to me

Comment: @ShahriarSirajSnigdho This is another story, but in terms of efficiency probably they're almost the same...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) 
        {
            var ele = GridMain.FindName("btn" + i);

            // @Archana you missed this line
            Button button = ele as Button;

            // Do what you want to do with your control 
            button.Background = background;
            button.Foreground = foreground;                
        }
```

Comment: BTW, I don't find honest your auto-answer. You should drop it and mark Archana one as the right one if it gave you the right direction to the solution

Comment: You can directly assign FindName value to Button type. No need of extra line( Button button = ele as Button)